# Showing Cyrillic in C# textbox

Tags: c#, unicode

How to transmute char array (string) with code of the text, in c# into show able Cyrillic string i.e. (1099 = ы), instead of gibberish.

```
string codes = 109910991099;
```

that string representation in Cyrillic = ыыы;
Current result shows [] (boxes).

Comment: Tip: `char x = (char)1099`

Comment: You can also use "\u044B" to encode the character in the string, e.g., `string codes = "\044b\u044b\u044b"`. (1099=0x44b).  `string codes = "ыыы"` is also legal.